Rancher certificate issues with letsencrypt
We have a sandbox Rancher cluster that autonomously renews its certificate via Let's Encrypt. Since it's a sandbox cluster, we only bring it up when needed. The certificate expired while the cluster was down. Now, we're encountering the following error: "Unable to connect to the server: x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid." Additionally, the cluster agent is also not connected. K8s Version is v1.26.8 Rancher Version is v2.7.6
I tried to connect to the controlplane via ssh and renew the cert but i didnt found any certs. So im kinda clueless now what to do
